# Ruby unable to install Ruby xslt- plugin

Tags: ruby

I am trying to install ruby xslt plugin [ruby-xslt](https://github.com/glejeune/ruby-xslt) 
however when I run the setup I get the following error

```
C:\Users\186\Downloads\ruby-xslt-master>ruby setup.rb
setup.rb:283: warning: key "bin-dir" is duplicated and overwritten on line 284
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from setup.rb:1578:in `<main>'
        1: from setup.rb:768:in `invoke'
setup.rb:788:in `load_rbconfig': uninitialized constant Config (NameError)
Did you mean?  RbConfig
```

Comment: `Config` has been deprecated in favour of `RbConfig` since ruby 1.9.3, and was removed in 2.2.0. You *could* update that `setup.rb` script, but... Why are you even running that in the first place? This looks like a legacy script to support installation on ancient ruby versions! You should just be able to run `gem install ruby-xslt` like the README says??

Comment: I want to convert transform xml to xslt so trying to install Ruby XSLT package

Comment: Ok. So why can't you just run the regular `gem install` command? There is nothing in the README about needing to run the command you're trying.

Comment: I am behind  the proxy so it will not allow me to. And I am unable to access my proxy information to do something with it

Comment: Then can you download the gem, transfer it to this machine, and install it directly? https://rubygems.org/downloads/ruby-xslt-0.9.10.gem

Comment: I will surely try that. Thanks. You can answer the question that Config has depreciated. I will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Config` has been deprecated in favour of `RbConfig` since ruby version `1.9.3`, and was removed completely in version `2.2.0`.

You *could* update that `setup.rb` script for compatibility with modern ruby, but I don't think there's any need to even run this in the first place? The installation instructions, outlined in the project README, makes no mention of it. My guess is that this is a legacy script, which was used to install the project many years ago.

You *should* be able to just run: `gem install ruby-xsl`. Or if you're somehow not able to run this directly, you can download the gem: https://rubygems.org/downloads/ruby-xslt-0.9.10.gem, then run `gem install` with this file.

In the (unlikely) event that you do need to re-build the gem from source, I'd advise trying [the instructions laid out in the project README](https://github.com/glejeune/ruby-xslt#installation):

```
ruby extconf.rb # see CONFIGURATION for more options
make
make test
make doc
sudo make install
```